# Is it possible to serialize a stream's contents in C# and then deserialize it in Python?

Tags: python, c#, .net, serialization

Bit of a weird case here. I have an existing function that writes a ZIP file to a stream.

```
await WriteZipToStream(streamToWriteTo);
```

I have another function that upload a string to a secure place.

```
await SaveStringInSecureWay(stringToSave);
```

I *have* to get the ZIP as a stream and I *have* to save it as a string. I'll then later need to deserialize the string back to a ZIP file in some Python code.

Is this possible? I'm struggling to figure out the correct way to serialize the stream contents that can then be deserialized from within Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a little prep first

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(); //First, convert the ZIP file stream into a byte array.
await WriteZipToStream(memoryStream);
byte[] zipBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

string base64ZipString = Convert.ToBase64String(zipBytes); //Convert the byte array to a Base64 encoded string

await SaveStringInSecureWay(base64ZipString); //you can use your SaveStringInSecureWay method to save this Base64 encoded string.
```

then the python

```
import base64

base64_zip_string = retrieve_saved_string()  # Replace with your retrieval method
zip_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_zip_string)
with open('output.zip', 'wb') as zip_file:
    zip_file.write(zip_bytes)
```

Comment: Would be more efficient to do `Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length)` and remove the `ToArray`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are talking about readable string, like base64 encoding.

If you are talking about binary streaming save to binary file ( upload a string to a secure place.) , then it is by nature the zip file.
If you received "readable string" as in base64 encoding, you save it to text file, then in python code you read the string and use base64 decoding to transfer it into binary (zip file). That is straightforward too.